# Marshmallow is asking for storage permission everytime even once given

Tags: java, android

I have created a new application and every page has a share button on it and on clicking share button it captures the screenshot and makes it shares via intent and over clicking on share button it ask for permission and once given it works smoothly for other devices except Android 6 as even once given permission Android 6 asks for it again and again

The code I have used on every page

```
Manifest:<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>


OnClick(View v) {
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1);
SHARE();
}
```

This code is written in 5 pages a five-page am having five page News category and on clicking on share button it should ask for permission but once given it should not ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are requesting permissions in that method. You need to check to see if permissions have been granted and only then request them.

See here for details https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting